# s2disk won't power down in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, hibernate

It actually saves the state. When it won't switch off i press the on-button 3 seconds and restart, it resumes ok.

Does anybody know how i can "debug" this switch-off-problem. I have a new laptop [Asus u44s](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks/Superior_Mobility/U44SG/#specifications) and just installed Ubuntu 12.04.

regards && tia

noircc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it helped to change in `/etc/uswsusp.conf`  `shutdown method` from `platform` to `shutdown` ([see another question on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/644219/s2disk-does-not-power-off-on-debian-with-kernel-3-10-on-thinkpad/651939#651939)).