# s2disk does not power off on Debian with kernel 3.10 on Thinkpad

Tags: linux, debian, hibernate, thinkpad, acpi

When I hibernate my Thinkpad T61 with s2disk, it does not power off. The problem occurred after migration to kernel 3.10 (3.2 works fine, 3.11 also broken).

Any clue how to fix or at least debug it?

Answer (score 0):

I hate answering my questions.

In my case it wasn't related to kernel. It helped to change in `/etc/uswsusp.conf`  `shutdown method` from `platform` to `shutdown`.

```
# shutdown method = platform
shutdown method = shutdown
```

Comment: Didn't work for me 